# How to set the background color of an Android tab?

Tags: android, user-interface, tabs, user-experience

I have a view pager and have tabs at the very top. Each tab has an icon. I am not using textviews for the tabs. I've tried searching for a way to change the background color of the tabs, but all I get is solutions involving use a textview for the tabs.

Is there a way to set the background color of the tabs without using a textview? I have set icons to the tabs.

Note: The tabs will all be the same color.

Comment: what tab libraries you used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be Awesome for you ,you can customize everything,set an icon or text or both ,change Background color and Everything

https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip